# events load and ready not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
$(document).on('ready load click',function(){
    console.log('hiihuhu')
})
```

I included the jquery script above.
The problem is the click event is firing but the load or ready event is not.
I don't see any error in my console.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried using the events one by one? I mean one at once?

Comment: No semi colon on either line?

Comment: The code works properly at my end. There is no problem in the snippet you provided. Have you enclosed this inside `<script type="text/javascript">`? Or at least inside `<script>` tag

Comment: every thing is right about that code, as I said the click event works, when I refresh the page I don't see any thing but when I click I see the message.
All I want is to execute an ajax request on load or ready. but when I tried this, I got this result that events are not firing.

Comment: I tried  one event every time but nothing happened

Comment: Unless your problem is that you're using a newer version of jQuery as Geeky answered, the problem is probably elsewhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which Version of jQuery are you using

According to jQuery docs

**$(document).on( "ready", handler ), deprecated as of jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 3.0. Note that if the DOM becomes ready before this event is attached, the handler will not be executed.**

```js
$( window ).load(function() {
 alert("hello");
});

$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click',function(){
     alert("in click event");
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>hello</div>
```

1. **Window onload:** :Is fired when all the content including images has been loaded
2. **document.ready** : Is fired after html document is loaded

So i guess you cannot combine all three events ready,load and click the way you have tried

Hope it helps

Comment: I understand these concepts but the document ready or load dose not fire at all, at least the window on load fired so i will use it even if I dont understand what stopped the document.ready and document.load from firing

Comment: and about  document.load .window.onload appears to be the most widely supported. In fact, some of the most modern browsers have in a sense replaced document.onload with window.onload.

Comment: this link could be of helpful to u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload